# Regarding Object/Class Instances in Java

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, instance

Consider the scenario below:

```
public class ClassA {

    private Main main;
    Object obj = new Object;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
    methodA() {  //called first
        obj.someFunction();
        main.someFunction();
    }
    methodB() {  //called second
        obj.someOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

Would methodB be using the same instance of "obj" as methodA? If not, how could the code be altered to make it so?

I apologize for such a basic question, but it is a concept that has been unclear for me since I started learning java, even after countless searches online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to visualize that, you can just print the object to see that hash:

```
public class ClassA {

    private Main main;
    Object obj = new Object;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
    methodA() {  //called first
        System.out.println(obj); //you should see the same hash as in methodB
        obj.someFunction();
        main.someFunction();
    }
    methodB() {  //called second
        System.out.println(obj); //you should see the same hash as in methodA
        obj.someOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I tried printing out the hashes, and now I know that my program is somehow changing the objects between the method calls. Now I just have to figure out where (:

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Java will not change objects behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

If you're test case is:

```
ClassA objectA = new ClassA(new Main());
objectA.methodA();
objectA.methodB();
```

with nothing in between the calls to `methodA()` then `methodB()` that would change the value of the `obj` instance variable, then yes, they would both use the same `obj` instance.